# What happens with QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyside

I want to create the GUI with this code. When i click Add New Object Button, it will show the pop up (I use QMainWindown) but i want to put the QLabel in here, it can not work

I dont know why.i hope everyone can give me more some advices. Thanks you

This is my code :

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.First(), 0, 0, 2, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Library")
        self.resize(700,660)
    #----------------------------------------FIRST COLUMN-------------------------------------
    def First(self):
        FirstFrame = QtGui.QFrame()
        FirstFrame.setFixedSize(230,700)

    # LABEL
        renderer_lb  = QtGui.QLabel("Renderer :")
        folders_lb = QtGui.QLabel("Folder :")
    #COMBOBOX
        self.renderer_cbx = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.renderer_cbx.addItem("Vray")
        self.renderer_cbx.addItem("Octane")
    # LIST VIEW FOLDER
        self.folders_lv = QtGui.QListView()
    # BUTTON
        addnewobject_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Add New Objects")
        newset_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("New Set")

    # DEFINE THE FUNCTION FOR FIRST FRAME
        Firstbox = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        Firstbox.addWidget(renderer_lb,0,0)
        Firstbox.addWidget(folders_lb,2,0,1,4)
        Firstbox.addWidget(self.renderer_cbx,0,1,1,3)
        Firstbox.addWidget(self.folders_lv,3,0,1,4)
        Firstbox.addWidget(addnewobject_btn,4,0,1,2)
        Firstbox.addWidget(newset_btn,4,3)
        Firstbox.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        FirstFrame.setLayout(Firstbox)

        addnewobject_btn.clicked.connect(self.addnewobject)

        return FirstFrame

    def addnewobject(self):
        window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        window.setWindowTitle('Select folder of new objects')
        window.setFixedSize(450,90)
        window.show()

        folder_lb = QtGui.QLabel("Folder : ")

        browser = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        browser.addWidget(folder_lb,0,0)
        window.setLayout(browser)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(window.exec_())
```

Comment: This is probably not the shortest possible example and also it is not clear what you mean by "does not work". What happens instead?

Answer (score 1):

Just as you did in the `First()` function, you could create an homemade widget using `QFrame`. Then you can set a central widget for your new window.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.First(), 0, 0, 2, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Library")
        self.resize(700,660)
        self.show()
    #----------------------------------------FIRST COLUMN-------------------------------------
    def First(self):
        FirstFrame = QtGui.QFrame()
        FirstFrame.setFixedSize(230,700)

    # LABEL
        renderer_lb  = QtGui.QLabel("Renderer :")
        folders_lb = QtGui.QLabel("Folder :")
    #COMBOBOX
        self.renderer_cbx = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.renderer_cbx.addItem("Vray")
        self.renderer_cbx.addItem("Octane")
    # LIST VIEW FOLDER
        self.folders_lv = QtGui.QListView()
    # BUTTON
        addnewobject_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Add New Objects")
        newset_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("New Set")

    # DEFINE THE FUNCTION FOR FIRST FRAME
        Firstbox = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        Firstbox.addWidget(renderer_lb,0,0)
        Firstbox.addWidget(folders_lb,2,0,1,4)
        Firstbox.addWidget(self.renderer_cbx,0,1,1,3)
        Firstbox.addWidget(self.folders_lv,3,0,1,4)
        Firstbox.addWidget(addnewobject_btn,4,0,1,2)
        Firstbox.addWidget(newset_btn,4,3)
        Firstbox.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        FirstFrame.setLayout(Firstbox)

        addnewobject_btn.clicked.connect(self.addnewobject)

        return FirstFrame

    def addnewobject(self):
        secondFrame = QtGui.QFrame()
        secondFrame.setFixedSize(230,700)
    # LABEL
        folders_lb = QtGui.QLabel("Folder :")

    # DEFINE THE FUNCTION FOR FIRST FRAME
        secondGridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        secondGridLayout.addWidget(folders_lb,2,0,1,4)
        secondGridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        secondFrame.setLayout(secondGridLayout)

        window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        window.setWindowTitle('Select folder of new objects')
        window.setFixedSize(600,700)

        window.setCentralWidget(secondFrame) # Here is the main change: setLayout(QLayout) to setCentralWidget(QWidget)
        window.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(window.exec_())
```

Is this intended for Maya? If yes, I recommand you not to use modal windows as it will quickly fed up the users.

Comment: Thanks you so much, i try it to support 3DsMax. I'm just a new guy. So that many thing is strange with me. Thanks you again.

Comment: I have one more question, do you have another the ways to do it, i try create a Frame inside def Addnewobject to put all thing together in here.

Comment: You mean, putting all the QFrame creation from Second() inside addnewobject()?

Comment: Yes, do you can do it, So sorry if i bother you, or you can give me some advices i will find it. Thanks so much

Comment: Edited my answer, the code is inside addnewobject() and the main (first) window is now modeless ( self.show() #Added line )

Comment: I see it, you are really smart, thanks you so much. How do you know it , can i make friend with you . I want to learn the Python, but really hard to find the documentation to learn it.

Comment: Hahaha, no I am not that smart. I just learned Python from scratch combined with Maya scripting commands. Try doing some simple stuff at the beginning. Start with testing all the different widgets PySide can offer, then mess arround with the signals and slots. To finish, connect your UI with 3dsMax's api.

Comment: For the documentation, I would recommend the Python and PySide docs. If you are really new in Python, go to this website: [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/)

Comment: Thanks you so much, i will follow your advices. Thanks you again.

Comment: As a final note, if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. I still need a small amount of reputation to be able to comment.